# Recursive procedure explanation

Tags: prolog, factorial

So I have the following working code in Prolog that produces the factorial of a given value of A:

```
factorial(0,1).
factorial(A,B) :- A>0, C is A-1, factorial(C,D), B is A*D.
```

I am looking for an explanation as to how this code works. I.e, what exactly happens when you ask the query: factorial(4, Answer).

Firstly,

```
factorial(0, 1).
```

I know the above is the "base case" of the recursive definition. What I am not sure of why/how it is the base case. My guess is that factorial(0, 1) inserts some structure containing (0, 1) as a member of "factorial". If so, what does the structure look like? I know if we say something like "rainy(seattle).", this means that Seattle is rainy. But "factorial(0, 1)"... 0, 1 is factorial? I realize it means factorial of 0 is 1, but how is this being used in the long run? (Writing this is helping me understand more as I go along, but I would like some feedback to make sure my thinking is correct.)

```
factorial(A,B) :- A>0, C is A-1, factorial(C,D), B is A*D.
```

Now, what exactly does the above code mean. How should I read it?

I am reading it as: factorial of (A, B) is true if A>0, C is A-1, factorial(C, D), B is A*D. That does not sound quite right to me... Is it?

"A > 0". So if A is equal to 0, what happens? It must not return at this point, or else the base case would never be used. So my guess is that A > 0 returns false, but the other functions are executed one last time. Did recursion stop because it reached the base case, or because A was not greater than 0? Or a combination of both? At what point is the base case used?

I guess that boils down to the question: What is the purpose of having both a base case and A > 0?

Sorry for the badly formed questions, thank you.

EDIT: In fact, I removed "A > 0" from the procedure and the code still works. So I guess my questions were not stupid at least. (And that code was taken from a tutorial.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is counterproductive to think of Prolog facts and rules in terms of data structures. When you write `factorial(0, 1).` you assert a fact to the Prolog interpreter that is assumed to be universally true. With this fact alone Prolog can answer questions of three types:

- What is the factorial of `0`? (i.e. `factorial(0, X)`; the answer is `X=1`)
- A factorial of what number is `1`? (i.e. `factorial(X,1)`; the answer is `X=0`)
- Is it true that a factorial of `0` is `1`? (i.e. `factorial(0,1)`; the answer is "Yes")

As far as the rest of your Prolog program is concerned, only the first question is important. That is the question that the second clause of your `factorial/2` rule will be asking at the end of evaluating a `factorial`.

The second rule uses comma operator, which is Prolog's way of saying "and". Your interpretation can be rewritten in terms of variables `A` and `B` like this:

> `B` is a factorial of `A` when `A>0`, and `C` is set to `A-1`, and `D` is set to the factorial of `C`, and `B` is set to `A` times `D`

This rule covers all `A`s above zero. The reference to `factorial(C,D)` will use the same rule again and again, until `C` arrives to zero. This is when this rule stops being applicable, so Prolog would grab the "base case" rule, and use `1` as its output. At this point, the chain of evaluating `factorial(C, D)` starts unwrapping, until it goes all the way to the initial invocation of the rule. This is when Prolog computes the final answer, and `factorial/2` returns "Yes" and produces the desired output value.

In response to your edit, removing the `A>0` is not dangerous only for getting the first result. Generally, you can ask Prolog to find you more results. This is when the `factorial/2` with `A>0` removed would fail spectacularly, because it would start going down the invocation chain of the second clause with negative numbers - a chain of calls that will end in numeric overflow or stack overflow, whichever comes first.

Comment: So when A > 0 returns false, does the function stop right then? Or would it first compute the other conditions? Oh also, is it significant that "factorial(C, D)" is to the left of "B is A*D"?

Comment: @Colton When any part of a comma-separated sequence returns `false`, Prolog "backtracks" and tries to find another assignment of variables to satisfy the rules. When this is no longer possible, Prolog goes back another level, until there's no other place to go. At that point Prolog tries other clauses of the rule, if any. Long story short, when `A>0` fails, Prolog stops, because that's the first clause in the chain.

Comment: @Colton Yes, it is significant that `factorial(C, D)` is to the left of `B is A*D`. Multiplication (and other binary rules) need at least two out of three variables to be "bound" in order to work (having all three is OK as well, if you need to perform a fact check). If you put `factorial(C, D)` to the right of multiplication, both `D` and `B` would be unknown at this point, so the `*/2` operator would fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you come from a procedural language background, the following C++ code might help. It mirrors pretty accurately the way the Prolog code executes (at least for the common case that A is given and B is uninstantiated):

```
bool fac(int a, int &b)
{
    int c,d;
    return
        a==0  &&  (b=1,true)
        ||
        a>0  &&  (c=a-1,true)  &&  fac(c,d)  &&  (b=a*d,true);
}
```

The Prolog comma operates like the sequential `&&`, and multiple clauses like a sequential `||`.

Answer (score 1):

My mental model for how prolog works is a tree traversal.

The facts and predicates in a prolog database form a *forest* of trees. When you ask the Prolog engine to evaluate a predicate:

```
?- factorial(6,N).
```

the Prolog engine looks for the tree rooted with the specified functor and arity (`factorial/2` in this case). The Prolog engine then performs a depth-first traversal of that tree trying to find a solution using unification and pattern matching. Facts are evaluated as they are; For predicates, the right-hand side of the `:-` operator is evaluated, walking further into the tree, guided by the various logical operators.

Evaluation stops with the first successful evaluation of a leaf node in the tree, with the prolog engine remembering its state in the tree traversal. On backtracking, the tree traversal continues from where it left off. Execution is finally complete when the tree traversal is completed and there are no more paths to follow.

That's why Prolog is a descriptive language rather than an imperative language: you *describe* what constitutes truth (or falsity) and let the Prolog engine figure out how to get there.